# How to fit iframe content with landscape orientation within device screen

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have a webpage that I have set to have a landscape orientation on mobile devices within which I have placed an iframe. My problem is I cant get the iframe to fit within the mobile device screen while in landscape orientation (full width and height matching the device screen). How may I be able to achieve this?

I am using CSS:

```
<style>
   body, html {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   #content {
     position:absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     top: 0
   }

  #content iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:none;
  }

  @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
      body {
         -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
         -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
         transform: rotate(-90deg);
         transform-origin: 50% 50%;

           }
     }
   </style>
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <iframe src="localhost/iframeTest/index.php" 
      allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
      class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen 
      mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen 
       msallowfullscreen width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't just use `rotate(-90deg)`. It calculates width and height and rotates afterwards. So its not scaled to your window. You propably need to calculate your width with JS

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment the problem is, that the size is calculated before you rotate it. To fix this you can use `vh, vw` sizes and just just `vw` for height and `vh` for width. Then you can rotate and translate it back into viewport.

```
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: translateY(100vh) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Check this codepen to see it working: https://codepen.io/pixelarbeit/pen/rpLbNe